# How to interpret the reward after defeating an monster

Tags: legends-of-andor

The manual states that after a monster is defeated, e.g. a gor, the players receive  2 gold **and/or** willpower. We assumed this means one of the following:

- 2 gold
- 1 gold and 1 willpower
- 2 willpower

to be divided between the players fighting and defeating it. However, based on the wording we aren't completely sure.

Is this assumption correct?

What if we look at other monsters, for example a skrall? The reward is then 4 gold **and or** willpower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.

The hero receives an amount of gold equal to the monster’s gold icon (found on the monster strength track) OR an amount of willpower equal to the monster’s willpower icon OR a combination of the two. Example: After defeating a gor, the hero may take 2 gold, 2 willpower, or 1 gold and 1 willpower.

[Edit] and of course, if you win 4, you can chose any combination of gold and willpower.